# Getting String from Json?

Tags: android, json, getstring

I have a strange problem in my android app. In one method I do this :

```
try {
 String r = responseBody.toString();
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(r);
 categorys = new String[jArray.length()];
 idcategory = new Integer[jArray.length()];
 System.out.println("lung " + jArray.length());
  for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsdata = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String idcat = jsdata.getString("id_category");
    idcategory[i] = Integer.valueOf(idcat);
    System.out.println("Id " + idcat);
    String namecategory = jsdata.getString("category_name");
    categorys[i] = namecategory;
    System.out.println("Category name  " + namecategory);
}
```

and everything works fine, I get from server the categorys and category's id. In an other method I do this (for an other response) :

```
try {
 String re = responseBody.toString();
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(re);
 System.out.println("lung " + jArray.length());
 titlephotos = new String[jArray.length()];
 photolink=new String[jArray.length()];
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsdata = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String titlephoto = jsdata.getString("title");                       
   System.out.println("titlu photo " + titlephoto);
   titlephotos[i] = titlephoto;

   String linkphoto=jsdata.getString("view");
   System.out.println("link photo"+ linkphoto);
   photolink[i]=linkphoto;
 }
}catch(JSONException e) {
  System.out.println("You are in catch");
}
```

and I get only one title photo an after that I get the message from catch(). If I don't put

```
String linkphoto=jsdata.getString("photo link");
System.out.println("link photo"+ linkphoto);
photolink[i]=linkphoto;
```

I get all the titles. I don't understand where is the problem,because the methods are similar, and the first one works fine. Can anyone help?

Thanks...

Comment: please add the JSON data. What if "photo link" is mistyped ?

Comment: now I found the solution...I should put "photo_link" instead of "photo link"...sorry:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is the space in 
String linkphoto=jsdata.getString("photo link");